# Mongo sort by either of 2 fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents where the `foo` field is always nested in `x` or `y` and not both.

```js
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb97b2937803b14255180"),
    "x": {
        "foo": 42
    },
    "y": { }
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb97b2937803b14255181"),
    "x": { },
    "y": {
        "foo": 24
    }
}
```

I want to sort by it and get

```js
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb97b2937803b14255181"),
    "x": { },
    "y": {
        "foo": 24
    }
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb97b2937803b14255180"),
    "x": {
        "foo": 42
    },
    "y": { }
}
```

It would be great if I can do it with `find().sort()` and not `aggregate()`, but an `aggregate()` answer would be appriciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sort key with `$ifNull` to fall back into `y.foo` if `x.foo` is not present then sort on the sort key.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "sortKey": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$x.foo",
          "$y.foo"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sortKey: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "sortKey"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y2RVLp52HiD)

---

Side note: It might be better if you can preprocess your documents and materialized a single sort key. You can then index the consolidated sort key to gain performance boost and simpler queries.

Comment: how would the query look if you used Aggregation Pipeline?

Comment: @yoloexpectz what do you mean? I am already using aggregation pipeline

Comment: my bad, i get it now - `$set` , `$sort` and `$unset` are your 3 stages!